# ¿Como puedo usar recursividad para este codigo?

Tags: javascript, recursión

hace poco empecé a aprender JavaScript y estuve haciendo algunos ejercicios básicos con conceptos muy básicos también de JavaScript, uno de ellos fue hacer una función que pase un numero binario a decimal. Bueno cuestión que ahora estoy aprendiendo recursividad y me preguntaba como puedo transformar mi código ya hecho a forma recursiva y que me funcione. Lo estuve pensando un rato pero no se me viene nada, así que si alguno de ustedes tiene alguna idea me vendría genial, gracias.

```
function BinarioADecimal(num) {
  let numero = 0
  let indice = 0
  for (let i = num.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    numero = numero + num[i] * 2 ** indice
    indice = indice + 1
  }
  return numero 
}
```

Comment: transformacion que depende de un estado anterior, condicion de salida, ver el stack crecer y decrecer ( o explotar ) en este caso una forma es tomar un bit transformarlo en su potencia de 2 y sumarlo a recursivamente una forma es tomar un bit transformarlo en su potencia de 2 y sumarlo a recursivamente una forma es tomar un bit transformarlo en su potencia de 2 y sumarlo a recursivamente ... hasta q no hay bits <- condicion de salida

Answer (score 1):

En mi ejemplo uso una sola funcion pero debes crear variables externas:

```
let number1 = "1011001111" // numeros a convertir
let number2 = "1101010"
let number3 = "10110110"

let pointer = 0; // variables auxiliares. 
let result, position;
// pointer actua como el indice de un for comenzando desde 0 hasta el length del numero, 
// position es igual pero al reves: empieza desde el length y va decrementando (el algoritmo para convertir lo pedia)
// y result almacena el resultado

function binarioADecimal(num) {
  if(position>=0){
    result = result + num[pointer] * (2**position)
    position--;
    pointer ++;
    return binarioADecimal(num); 
  } else {
    pointer = 0;
    return result
  };
}

result = 0;
position = number1.length-1
console.log(binarioADecimal(number1))
// antes de convertir el siguiente numero debemos resetear el result e igualar position a la longitud del nuevo numero a convertir
result = 0;
position = number2.length-1 
console.log(binarioADecimal(number2))
// aca tambien
result = 0;
position = number3.length-1
console.log(binarioADecimal(number3))
```

ah y tu funcion siempre da 0.

Answer (score 0):

La principal regla de una función recursiva es que debe tener una forma de detener la recursividad, de lo contrario sigue hasta el infinito y da un error (que da origen al nombre de esta página). Esto, en la mayoría de los casos, se realiza con un "if"

Transformar un for en recursivo es muy fácil, en un for tienes

```
for (let i = num.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Si te fijas en el for existe una condición para seguir la ejecución (i>=0), este será nuestro if

Nuestra primera aproximación queda así:

```
function BinarioADecimal_Recur(num,indice,i) {
  if(i>=0){
    numero = numero + num[i] * 2 ** indice //Esto es un ejemplo
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

El siguiente paso, es integrar la recursividad propiamente tal. Donde? Pues en lo que vendría siendo "Numero", porque es el ***retorno***

Entonces la función queda así:

```
function BinarioADecimal_Recur(num,indice,i) {
  if(i>=0){
    return BinarioADecimal_Recur(num,indice+1,i-1) + num[i] * 2 * indice;
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

Ahora bien, si te fijas la función tiene 3 parámetros que son los mismos que tú tienes en tu función, y en cada recursión los sumamos y restamos, de igual manera que la función con el for.

Además, estos parámetros se pueden calcular por programación, para estos casos se crea una función inicial.
(Nota: En lenguajes decentes, donde existe la sobrecarga de funciones, se ocupa el mismo nombre, en javascript tendremos que poner otro)

```js
function BinarioADecimal(num) {
  return BinarioADecimal_Recur(num, 0, num.length - 1);
}
function BinarioADecimal_Recur(num,indice,i) {
  if(i>=0){
    return BinarioADecimal_Recur(num,indice+1,i-1) + num[i] * 2 ** indice;
  }
  return 0; 
}

console.log( BinarioADecimal("10"));
console.log( BinarioADecimal("1011"));
```

De esta manera podemos llamar a la función ingresando un solo parámetro

Este código ya es recursivo y funciona.

---

(Aquí otra forma de hacerlo)

Ahora bien, generalmente no tenemos ese for que nos ayuda a empezar la creación de la función recursiva.
Pero en este caso tenemos un array, aquí generalmente lo que se hace es ir pasando el array sacando un elemento (puede ser menos el primer elemento o el último) depende del contexto.

```js
function BinarioADecimal(num){
   return BinarioADecimal_Recur(num.split("")); //convertimos a rray
}
function BinarioADecimal_Recur(num){
   if(num.length>0){
      let numero = num[0]; //tomamos el primer elemento
      //slice(1) retorna una array sin el primer elemento
      return BinarioADecimal_Recur(num.slice(1)) + numero * 2 ** (num.length-1);
   }
   return 0;
}


console.log(BinarioADecimal("10"));
console.log(BinarioADecimal("1011"));
console.log(BinarioADecimal("101"));
```

Comment: Pero los resultados no dan... 1011 no es 8 y 101 no es 4

Comment: @Pipe toda la razón, se me pasó un '*'. Gracias por avisarme

Answer (score 0):

```js
function bin2dec(num) {
  res = 0
  // si aún hay bits
  if ("" !== num.slice(0, 1)) {
    // multiplicamos left bit por la potencia de 2 correspondiente
    res = (num.slice(0, 1) * 2 ** (num.length - 1))
    console.log(`num: ${num}, res: ${res}`)
    // y sumamos al resultado de aplicar sobre el resto de bits
    res += bin2dec(num.slice(1))
  }
  return res
}

dec = bin2dec("01000101")
console.log(dec, "lol")
```

Answer (score 0):

La versión mas sencilla que se me ocurre es esta:

```js
function bin2dec(bin, index=null){
  index=(index ?? bin.length)-1; //Si se llama sin parámetro index, usamos la longitud del string
  
  return index < 0
    ? 0 //Si el index es menor a 0 retornamos 0
    : (bin[index] << (bin.length-index-1)) + bin2dec(bin, index); //sino, retornamos el valor de ese bit + la suma del siguiente
}

console.log(bin2dec("1001"));
console.log(bin2dec("111"));
console.log(bin2dec("1011"));
```